# Homework Sales calculator

Tags: javascript

Yesterday I submitted this problem, got terrific responses but my code still didn't work. I modified my code based on another student's code that works, but my code still won't calculate but it validates in javascript. Any suggestions. This homework is due TONIGHT!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4       /loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Price Calculator</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fixOrder() {
        const TAX = 0.975;
        var numPrice;
        var total;
        var tax;

        numPrice = parseFloat(document.getElementById("cost").value, 10);
        tax      = parseFloat(document.getElementById("tax").value, 10);
        total    = parseFloat(document.getElementById("total").value, 10);
        numPrice = numPrice * TAX;
        total    = numPrice;
        total    = document.getElementById("total").value = "$" + total.toFixed(2);

        if (isNaN(numPrice)) {
            alert("Sorry,you must enter a numeric value to place order");
            numPrice = 0;
        }
    }
</script>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#00f3F1">

    <h1 align="left">Price Calculator</h1>

    <form name="form" id="form">
       <p>Price: <input type="text" id="cost" name="cost" value="" onchange=
       "fixOrder" /></p>

       <p>Tax: &nbsp; <input type="text" id="tax" name="tax" value="" onchange=
       "fixOrder" /></p>

       <p>Total: <input type="text" id="total" name="total" value="" disabled=
       "disabled" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Could you link to the other question and fix the code formatting for `function fixOrder()` ? Thanks.

Comment: As jason answered you need to call the funtion correctly in the onclick event. Plus you want to reconsider this line, since you want to calculate something: `total = document.getElementById("total").value = "$" + total.toFixed(2);
`

Comment: What doesn't work is it won't calculate.

Comment: I can't use an onclick because we are not suppose to use a button. When I type in the amount in the Price textbox and hit return the amount is suppose to show in the Total textbox, but it doesn't. My isNaN alert box popup doesn't pop up when the value is not a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/tdrGQ/)

Your onchange event is `onchange="fixOrder"` which is not really doing anything.  If you change it to `fixOrder()` you will call the function `fixOrder` when the change event is fired.

---

#### Furthermore:

- I don't think `const` is a reserved word in JavaScript.  I don't think JS has constants.  You should change that line from `const TAX` to `var TAX`;
- Unlike `parseInt`, which takes two arguments (string and base/radix), `parseFloat` only takes one argument (string), so you can remove the `, 10` from it

---

I imagine you want something like:

```
function fixOrder() {
    var TAX = 0.0975;
    var numPrice;
    var total;
    var tax;

    numPrice = parseFloat(document.getElementById("cost").value);
    tax      = parseFloat(document.getElementById("tax").value);
    total    = parseFloat(document.getElementById("total").value);

    numPrice = numPrice + (tax || numPrice * TAX);
    total    = numPrice;
    var dec  = new Number((total+'').split('.')[1])  || 0;
    total    = document.getElementById("total").value =
                  "$" + Number(parseInt(total)
                      + '.'
                      + Math.round(
                          ( (dec+''.split('').reverse().join('') )/100 + '').split('').reverse().join('')
                        )).toFixed(2);
                        );

    if (isNaN(numPrice)) {
        alert("Sorry,you must enter a numeric value to place order");
        numPrice = 0;
    }
}
```

This will use the dollar amount of tax you enter, or if that doesn't exist, it will use the constant rate that you have supplied at the beginning (this was changed from .975 to .0975).

Also, notice the new calculation from total, we're taking the decimal part of the number, dividing it by 100 to get to two decimal places, reversing it back so it's in the proper order again, and then rounding it to the nearest 1 (cent).

---

#### HTML Body:

```
  <h1 align="left">Price Calculator</h1>

  <form name="form" id="form">
     <p>Price: <input type="text" id="cost" name="cost" value="" onchange="fixOrder()" /></p>

     <p>Tax: &nbsp; <input type="text" id="tax" name="tax" value="" onchange="fixOrder()" /></p>

     <p>Total: <input type="text" id="total" name="total" value="" disabled="disabled" /></p>
  </form>
```

Comment: I canged everything you suggested, even took out the 10 from the argument. When this code works the amount in the Price textbox and the tax textbox should show in the total textbox. It doesn't and that's the problem. My classmate's code is similar to mine, but works, kind of. Her alert box pops up too soon.

Comment: I added the `toFixed` back in, and also defaulted the `dec` to `0` if there was no decimal.  Everything should work, you have to hit tab to see the changes.  Make sure your body of your HTML is the same as the above, with the modified `onchange` event call.

Comment: +1 nicely done.  Not sure this can be handed in, though ;-)  Seems a bit beyond the original assignment.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the `onchange` to

```
fixOrder()
```

Comment: HTML doesn't have an `onChange`, but it does have an `onchange`.

Comment: correct @vol7ron.  I was focused on the `fixOrder()`.  Edited.

Comment: heh I know, but some people are picky :)  Actually, I'm not sure if HTML spec is case sensitive, but I know XHTML is, which I do all my pages in.

Answer (score 0):

When calling a function in JavasScript by an event, you need to mention the () after the name of the function you want to call.

Comment: I appreciate everyone answers. They were helpful. I think I should go to the chat room now as soon as I figure out how to log in to it.